# how to convert string 0000-00-00 in flat file to datetime in database using ssis

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ssis, etl

i have a .txt file, i using SSIS to import data to database. i has converted string `YYYY-MM-DD` to datetime using SSIS but string `0000-00-00` is not convert to `NULL`

example if value `2019-02-15` => import data ok, when value `0000-00-00` i want import data to a filed table in database is NULL

thanks you!

Comment: One would read the last column the same as one reads the previous column. I don't believe I understand your precise question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please update your question to include a few lines of sample data, and see [ask] and [mcve] for additional details on what to include in a question.

Comment: It should read it as a blank/null value.  Please provide data examples of what you have and what is happening and how you are importing it and to what destination

Comment: i have .txt file, i using SSIS to import data to database. i has converted string YYYY-MM-DD to datetime using SSIS but string 0000-00-00 is not convert to NULL

Comment: @MuMot - You can use the if condition to convert that to Null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the column name is `[RawColumn]` add a derived column with the following expression:

```
[RawColumn] == "0000-00-00" ? NULL(DT_DATE) : (DT_DATE)[RawColumn]
```

**References**

- [? : (Conditional) (SSIS Expression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/conditional-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017)
- [== (Equal) (SSIS Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/equal-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017)
- [NULL (SSIS Expression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/null-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: thanks you! i done. I have another question to ask for your help.
if string end of line is blank, how insert data to database. example structure .txt file
<string1; string2; string3> when string3 = blank